# Execution order of goal when a plugin goal in attached to a lifecycle phase in maven

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am trying to understand the maven goal execution order.

So i have a pom which attaches `maven-antrun-plugin` `run` goal to `clean` phase of maven lifecycle build.

When a run `mvn clean` i get the output as shown in output section:
Now my questions are:
1 why did `maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean)` goal executed as i have attached 
which goal to run i.e `pre-process-classes`... so does my goal get added to the default goal list that maven have or it can be override ? basically how maven decide which goal to execute ?

2 In Plugin section i only have `artifactId` and `version` but no `groupId`. so how did maven find the correct plugin.. isnt groupId necessary ?

**Output**

```
 --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ second_third ---
 Deleting D:\tmp\maven\first_second\target

 --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.1:run (pre-process-classes) @ second_third ---
 Executing tasks
echo] Build Dir: D:\tmp\maven\first_second\target
```

---

**pom.xml**

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.second_third_maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>second_third</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <build>
  <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>pre-process-classes</id>
              <phase>clean</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <echo>Build Dir: ${project.build.directory}</echo>
              </tasks>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the 2nd question:

```
By default, Maven will search the groupId org.apache.maven.plugins 
for prefix-to-artifactId mappings for the plugins it needs to
perform a given build.
```

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html

section "Configuring Maven to Search for Plugins"